# How to change a Bootstrap class list-group-item active depending on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have got a couple of html files that share exactly some lines of the code. I have that code with an include and I call that in every single page. It's basically a menu or better saying, a Bootstrap list-group. Here is the code:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/page1.php" class="list-group-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> Page1</a>
    <a href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/page2.php" class="list-group-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Page2</a>
    <a href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/page3.php" class="list-group-item active"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> Page3</a>
    <a href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/page4.php" class="list-group-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i> Page4</a>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that, I need my active class to change depending on which page I'm visiting. Therefore, we can say that the menu is only 99% the same, I mean, that class needs to be changed.

What's the best approach, recommendation or solution to tackle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can, on document ready, check the URL and then apply the `active` class to the element you need.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.IndexOf('page1') > -1) {
    $(".list-group:first-child").addClass("active");
    }

    // ... other cases, using switch for each

});
```

Something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can done through jquery

```
$(".list-group-item").on("click",function(){
    $(".list-group-item.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: jignesh, I don't think that is what the OP is asking. Your code would change the class on click but he would only see it for a split second. He needs the class to be set to the correct menu item as soon as he lands on the corresponding page